# Getting logs from IBM Z/OS

Tags: db2, zos, db2-zos

I am new to Mainframe concepts and haven't used any IBM Z-series machines before. But now I need to get db2 logs from the Z/OS platform.

I previously collected logs from IBM AS400 using JT400.jar.(will execute remote command and read the output using java).  But for Z/OS, I could not find such things from documentations.

So I need to know the possibilities for the following cases.

1. Running a remote command and read it's output using any API like JT400.
2. Forwarding the logs as Syslogs to any SIEM solutions((Like [ManageEngine EventLog Analyzer](https://www.manageengine.com/products/eventlog/) or [ArcSight ESM](https://www.microfocus.com/en-us/products/siem-security-information-event-management/overview)) without any Third-party Installations)
3. Listing Log files using SSH connection, because I heard that Z/os will have some Unix properties too(for example using JSCH)

Even if there are any other possibilities, please mention below. It would be really helpful. Based on the possibilities only I could consider buying a Z/OS mainframe.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are SDSF API(Access through Java) available on the z/OS unix shell. that can help to read the logs(DB2 Master log, System log etc).

Comment: Thanks @Premkumar.  I will check it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the log for DB2 go on SDSF type the command below:

```
da;pre *mstr
```

Answer (score 0):

In general there are commercial offerings to offload log and metric data from z/OS.  Ones that come to mind are:

- IBM Common Data Provider
- Syncsort IronStream
- BMC CorreLog

You could likely pull something of your own together but a better definition of which logs you want to consume would be useful.  There are many on z/OS.

Comment: Hi, @hogstrom I particularly need to monitor DB2 Logs. Is there any chance to extract only those logs?

Comment: When you say Db2 logs do you mean job logs from the DSNxMSTR address space or Tx Log files.  I assume you mean the former

Comment: Depending on your intent (processing the logs / archiving the logs), this question might be more appropriate in SuperUser

Comment: @Hogstorm, I checked with DB2 LUW, in which I found a Command called db2audit [https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002072.html]. I extracted logs using this command. I think these logs are enough for my analysis. Is this facility available in Z/OS? I looked the doc, They gave procedure to extract the logs as delimited files. But I want those logs in *.log or *.txt file same as in LUW.  Is it possible?